# How to handle salt in password based encryption

Tags: encryption, passwords

I'm learning to do proper crytographic implementations, and I thought as an exercise I would create an encrypted text editor.

My first attempt used a SHA-512 hash of a user-provided password as the key, and it functioned just fine. Though I was storing the IV in the header of the file, unprotected and that had me worried.

Then I read on stackoverflow that I should be using SecretKeyFactory (I'm using Java) to do PBE, and now I additionally need to provide a salt. So now I'm storing the salt in the header as well, but that would seem to ruin the whole purpose of having a salt. So how is this supposed to work? When I have Alice pick a password for her file when she saves, am I supposed to say "Here, memorize this random number along with your password."? I would like for the resulting file to be able to be e-mailed to Bob, so the salt can't be stored locally.

As my app stands, the IV and salt are out in the open. I would like for my user to only have to know the password when they send their file to Bob while remaining cryptographically secure, but I can't find any examples of how this is done.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe to store an IV along with the data, that is how IVs are used. Your method is ok, pick a block cipher, use cipher block chaining and an IV, and you're away.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create a key and iv from a passphrase, but one of the more common ones involves [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) with SHA-1, in an algorithm that takes some salt and other things into account, to build a sufficiently bit-mixed key and iv.

The technical standard is the PKCS#5 v2.0 PBKDF2 algorithm, to which OpenSSL implements a C interface to a method that can do this, but as far as I know, no command line method.